# Should Rails helpers assume an instance variable exists or should they receive them as parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm wondering if there's a specific programming principle (Demeter?) that supports the idea that Rails helpers should never use controller instance variables, rather, they should receive such variables as function parameters. For example, assume my `ChickensController#squawk` action creates an instance variable called `@egg`. Furthermore, assume the `squawk` view contains a call to a helper called `cockadoodledoo`, implemented like so:

```
def cockadoodledoo
  @egg.to_s
end
```

Would it be better or unnecessarily verbose to pass `@egg` as a parameter, such that the view calls `cockadoodledoo(@egg)` and for the helper to resemble:

```
def cockadoodledoo(egg)
  egg.to_s
end
```

I hope one of you happy hackers is bored enough on a Friday afternoon to assert an answer. Cockadoodledoo!

[This question here is similar, but was never accurately answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274569/ruby-on-rails-helpers-using-instance-variables-in-helpers)

Comment: Oooh so many nice answers and only one checkmark to give.... Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Receive them as a param. Otherwise, as the app grows, it gets very difficult to trace where the instance vars are being set when refactoring, troubleshooting, etc.

Also, I believe there's a general best practice to only use instance vars in views within the initial template...and from there you should pass the var into helpers and other partials.

Comment: Anyone know where this best practice is mentioned or what it's named?

Comment: Fabio, I disagree. Certainly we don't want to enforce draconian rules in the Art of Programming, but there is great value in naming things. For example, the "DRY principle."

Answer (score 21):

I'd say you should always pass the variables explicitly to your helper for 2 reasons:

- you control exactly what you do
- above all, you can test your helper

Comment: I didn't think about the testability. Uh, did I just get caught with my pants down? (Yes, I should write more tests.)

Comment: Improving the ability to test the helper here is key. Thanks for calling this explicitly.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if there is any named principle governing this sort of thing but I would pass an argument. Not only will the argument make your helper easier to test and your application's data flow easier to follow but it will also let you use one helper for a single instance as well as a list; if you pass an argument then both:

```
<%= cockadoodledoo @egg %>
```

and:

```
<% @eggs.each do |egg| %>
    <%= cockadoodledoo egg %>
<% end %>
```

will work as expected without introducing a special `cockadoodledoo` that handles a list in `@eggs` rather than a single `@egg`.

Answer (score 8):

Since helper messages are mixed in to all controllers, hence available to all views (including partials and layouts), it's always wise to establish a clear contract - the parameters.

The only exception I could think of is when a instance variable is also available to all views and controllers, like a menu or something similar.

Comment: No reason, I was just trying hard to find one (you know, every rule has an exception), but I think I might had pushed too hard.