# Syntax for select options helper method for second distant has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many-through, form-helpers

How do you correctly fill in the following syntax to create a dropdown select tag with each option being the data of another table?

```
<%= form_for(@celebrity, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :image %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.label :character %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:character, :celebrity_id, @characters, :id, :name)  %>   #this line is the question
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

I followed the API documentation here, but it doesn't seem to work.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

```
class Celebrity < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :characters, through: :char_celeb_joins
    has_many :char_celeb_joins

    has_many :universes, through: :characters

end


class Character < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :universes, through: :univ_char_joins
  has_many :univ_char_joins

  has_many :celebrities, through: :char_celeb_joins
  has_many :char_celeb_joins

end


class Universe < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :characters, through: :char_univ_joins
    has_many :char_univ_joins

    has_many :celebrities, through: :characters
end
```

But I get a 
`undefined method 'merge' for :name:Symbol`
in the browser, when I go to a view that brings up this code.
`NoMethodError in Celebrities#edit`

Comment: Do you want to list the `characters` or `celebrities` in the drop-down?

Comment: And also that `form code` belongs which `view` and where it is placed?

Comment: This is the celebrity form. I wish to show characters in the dropdown.

yes, the form code is where it needs to be. it renders perfectly if i remove the line I am trying to add here.

Comment: So,you have to list the characters.Then why you are using `celebrity_id`.It should be `character_id` and it makes sense right.What attributes you have in the celebrities table?

Comment: In celebrities table, i have name, some image magic columns, the two usual datetime attributes, and the id, which is not listed in the schema. it's still giving me `undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol`

Comment: In order to make that work,there should be a `belongs_to` association.In your case it is `celebrity belongs to character`. And also which table has `celebrity_id` column?

Comment: it has a has many through association, not a belongs to. I need a many to many relationship, so belongs to wouldn't work for my needs. A second reason is to allow `celebrities.universes` and `celebrities.characters`. celebrities and universes are distant, but they've been joined via rails methods.

Comment: Ofcourse! But it should be a `belongs_to` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` to work this out. And which table has `celebrity_id`?

Comment: The `:char_celeb_joins` table contains all the foreign keys., same with the `:univ_char_joins` table.

Why does using `has_many :through` not allow access to the associated records?

Comment: funny. why does this question get a downvote? I searched on SO, and there weren't similar questions like it. If it's too simple, and you know the answer, you can just answer it, and get points instead.

Comment: Hi, Pavan. I did try your solution, but it requires a belongs_to, when I really want has_many :through. That may be my fault, not your answer's. I went and found jquery tokenInput (select2 also does what I am trying to do), which implemented things better than what I had originally intended here. http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields I can't attest to it working, I can't really mark it as the accepted answer, right? But I really appreciate your help and input.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to this line

```
<%= f.collection_select(:character, :celebrity_id, @characters, :id, :name)  %>
```

When using with `form_for`,you have to set it like this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:celebrity_id, @characters, :id, :name)  %>
```

And also your `form_for object` is `@celebrity` and you are giving `:character` as object to `collection_select`.It should be `:celebrity` in the `collection_select` too.Ofcourse you have worry about this when using `collection_select` without `form_for`.In your case it would be

```
<%= collection_select(:celebrity, :celebrity_id, @characters, :id, :name)  %>
```

Comment: I get a no method error for `:celebrity_id` using the second line you provided.

are the arguments correct, if i am trying to select all the associated characters with a celebrity, in the celebrity form?

Comment: @gwho Which line you are referring to?

Comment: @gwho first answer my questions which are under comments of your question.Then i can able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper:

**Writer this code in any of the helper:**

```
def character_for_select
   Character.all.collect { |m| [m.id, m.name] }
end
```

**Update your form**

```
<%= form_for(@celebrity, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.label :character %>
<%= f.select(:character, character_for_select, :prompt => 'Select character') %>
<%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

You will get your answer :)

Comment: why does it require a custom helper? Isn't the rails helper method suppoes tdo be able to handle this?

Comment: if you want then `<%= f.select(:character, Character.all.collect { |m| [m.id, m.name] } , :prompt => 'Select character') %>`

Comment: I get an undefined method :character

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select). In your case, your code should be something like this:

**app/helpers...**

```
def options_for_characters( selected=nil )
  options = Character.all.map { |c| [d.id, c.name] }
  options_for_select( options, selected )
end
```

**app/views...**

```
   ...
   <%= f.select(:character, options_for_characters, :prompt => 'Select character') %>
   ...
```

Comment: Try to receive it as a param. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474596/should-rails-helpers-assume-an-instance-variable-exists-or-should-they-receive-t

Comment: why? and what does decoupling have to do with the OP?