# Mixing code HTML in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following works however it appears very clunky when I see some of the streamlined Ruby code others use.

Is this the correct way to code when mixing Ruby and HTML  in a helper?

```
def display_children(children)
  if children.count == 0
    "<p>No child records exist</p>".html_safe
  else  
    s = ""
    s << "<table class='table table-bordered text-center'>"
    children.in_groups_of(4) do |row_children|
      s << "<tr>"
      row_children.each do |child|
        s << "<td class='col-md-3'>"

        if child
          s << link_to(child.name, child)
        else
          s << '&nbsp;'
        end

        s << "</td>"
      end
      s << "</tr>"  
    end
    s << "</table>"
    s.html_safe
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is remove all the code from the helper and put it in a partial.

Code for selecting HTML output is generally embedded right into the HTML. Helpers are used to run more complex code like querying and prepping data to be displayed to the user.

Comment: So does a helper ever produce html or simply return raw data to a view to be displayed as html?

Comment: It doesn't "produce" HTML but you can get it to return HTML like you were doing in your code. What you're thinking of is a partial. Partials "produce", or more preferably phrased, "render" HTML for the browser. When you call a helper in your views, it's just calling a regular method/function/subroutine. Nothing special is happening. Just remember your method is in a helper module and not a controller class. This post should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474596/should-rails-helpers-assume-an-instance-variable-exists-or-should-they-receive-t